# ID repeats how do i reduce

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I have two tables and a linking table between them,
One of users and one of vacations and a linking table of likes,
I try to bring up all the vacations that a certain user did not like
And I get the same vacation twice because two other people liked her.
Is there a way NSQL will bring me just one of them.

These are the users

```
id  u_name

1   Gabi    Ashkenazi   
2   Johnny  Tribiani    
3   Bernie  Stinson 
4   Goku    son 
5   Bo  Bennett
```

These are the vacations

```
id  v_name

1   Venice
2   Rome
3   Maldives
4   Tokyo
5   Israel
6   Berlin
7   Prague
8   never Land
```

And the linking table looks like this

```
id  u_id   v_id
5   2       7
3   1       6
4   2       5
9   4       4
```

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT ...` to get rid of duplicate results.

Comment: Add the code you tried and the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? Find all the vacations that Johnny likes and then return the list that he doesn't like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vacations 
WHERE v_name not IN 
(
  SELECT v_name 
  FROM Users 
  JOIN Linking 
  ON Users.ID = Linking.U_id 
  JOIN Vacations On Linking.v_id = Vacations.ID
  WHERE Users.ID = 2
);
```